# Strange Behaviour of replaceAll method of String

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

I am facing strange behaviour of replaceAll method of String class.

I have a string buffer which contain below data

```
keyRPT1={keyRPT11=01|keyRPT19=01}|keyRPT3={keyRPT11=03|keyRPT19=01}|keyRPT8={keyRPT11=08|keyRPT19=01}
```

i write below code to replace the `"keyRPT11=08|keyRPT19=01"` with `"keyRPT11=08|keyRPT19=2"`

i am using below code for that

```
String complementaryInformation = "keyRPT1={keyRPT11=01|keyRPT19=01}|keyRPT3={keyRPT11=03|keyRPT19=01}|keyRPT8={keyRPT11=08|keyRPT19=01}";

complementaryInformation = complementaryInformation.replaceAll("keyRPT11=08|keyRPT19=01","keyRPT11=08|keyRPT19=2");
```

replaceAll give me the unexpected output

```
keyRPT1={keyRPT11=01|keyRPT11=08|keyRPT19=2}|keyRPT3={keyRPT11=03|keyRPT11=08|keyRPT19=2|keyRPT8={keyRPT11=08|keyRPT19=2|keyRPT11=08|keyRPT19=2}
```

when i am using replace method then i'll get the right output

```
keyRPT1={keyRPT11=01|keyRPT19=01}|keyRPT3={keyRPT11=03|keyRPT19=01}|keyRPT8={keyRPT11=08|keyRPT19=2}
```

Any idea guys??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `|` symbol which has special meaning in regex.

```
complementaryInformation = complementaryInformation.replaceAll("keyRPT11=08\\|keyRPT19=01","keyRPT11=08|keyRPT19=2");
```

`replaceAll()` method takes regex pattern as first parameter. `replace()` method does not take regex as parameter.

Comment: but the same is working when i am calling replace method. why it is so?

Comment: @MahendraAthneria: See Rubrick's answer. `replace` doesn't use regular expressions. When you're confused as to why two methods are behaving differently, **consult the documentation first**.

Comment: @Mahendra: `replaceAll()` method takes regex pattern as first parameter. `replace()` method does not take regex as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

String.replaceAll() takes a regular expression, whereas String.replace() takes a literal.